Tailwind CSS not applying
I'm new at Tailwind css.
It's not applying even though I followed the installation guide. I don't know where the problem is.
So, if I comment out the linking of styles.css, I don't see any effect. As soon as I use styles.css, the font changes which reflects that Tailwind is working but if I apply the classes, it doesn't work at all.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="text-red-500">

Here's the tailwind.config.js :
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};


"but if I apply the classes" - what files are you adding the CSS classes to? Are they included in the public folder which you've set as the content field for your Tailwind config?

yes the index.html and styles.css are both in the public folder

Check your html file path
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/**/*.html',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

Ensure your styles.css file includes the Tailwind directives
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

Run Tailwind CLI to Generate the CSS
npx tailwindcss -i yourpath/style.css -o yourpath/output.css --watch


when i run the tailwind CLI which path do i put on both the your path
